# How to set x axis labels as dates in pandas plot with a dataframe timestamp column

Tags: pandas, jupyter

I have a pandas dataframe (Jupyter) with two column, a datetime64[ns] (named day) and int64 (named events).

I want to plot the int64 column, using as x axis labels the datetime64[ns] (properly formatted).

I tried:

events_per_day.plot(kind='line', xticks=events_per_day['day'], ...

but I get:

TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need parameters `x` and `y` in [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), `kind='line'` can be omit because default value:

```
events_per_day.plot(x ='day', y='events')
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(45)
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
events_per_day = pd.DataFrame({'day': rng, 'events': np.random.randint(10, size=10)})  
print (events_per_day)
         day  events
0 2017-04-03       3
1 2017-04-04       0
2 2017-04-05       5
3 2017-04-06       3
4 2017-04-07       4
5 2017-04-08       9
6 2017-04-09       8
7 2017-04-10       1
8 2017-04-11       5
9 2017-04-12       9

events_per_day.plot(x ='day', y='events')
```

[image: graph]

Some formating by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
events_per_day['day'] = events_per_day['day'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
events_per_day.plot(x ='day', y='events', rot=45)
```

[image: graph1]